# issue with distributed tracing in Azure app insight ,node js and axios

Tags: node.js, axios, azure-application-insights

We are having an issue with distributed tracing in our microservice architecture project. Microservices are implemented as azure functions in node js. Communication between microservices is made through HTTP using axios . As per Microsoft documentation it supports the Tracecontext in distributed tracing by setting the operationId in appinsight properties but for some reason its not setting properly and operationId is different in each of the microservice.

Note:- When I execute the code locally (using the appinsightkey) operationId is passed as expected and it works well but when we deploy the code to azure cloud it doesn't work. we have raised a ticket with Microsoft but haven't received much information yet (Refer below link). Looking for a feedback to understand what is missing out which is causing the issue.

Npm Modules used
"applicationinsights": "^1.7.5"
"axios": "^0.19.2",
Node js version:- 12.13.0 (during deployment to cloud)

https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/710

Answer (score 0):

> Due to how Azure Functions (and other FaaS services) handle incoming
> requests, they are not seen as http requests to the Node.js runtime.
> For this reason, Request -> Dependency correlelation will not work out
> of the box. To enable tracking here, you simply need to grab the
> context from your Function request handler, and wrap your Function
> with that context.
>
> You do not need to make any changes to your existing Function logic.
> Instead, you can update the default export of your httpTrigger to be
> wrapped with some Application Insights logic.

As shown in [Azure Functions Example with axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights#azure-functions-example), below has inline explanation comments (below is just raw JS, not TS, adjust accordingly if you are using typescript):

```js
const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup("ikey") 
    .start();
// for configuration, refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights#configuration 
// default values shown there
 
const axios = require("axios");
 
/**
 * No changes required to your existing Function logic
 */
const httpTrigger = async function (context, req) {
    const response = await axios.get("https://httpbin.org/status/200");
// just example call
 
    context.res = {
        status: response.status,
        body: response.statusText,
    };
};
 
// Default export wrapped with Application Insights FaaS context propagation
export default async function contextPropagatingHttpTrigger(context, req) {
    // Start an AI Correlation Context using the provided Function context
    const correlationContext = appInsights.startOperation(context, req);
 
    // Wrap the Function runtime with correlationContext
    return appInsights.wrapWithCorrelationContext(async () => {
        const startTime = Date.now(); // Start trackRequest timer
 
        // Run the Function
        await httpTrigger(context, req);
 
        // Track Request on completion
        appInsights.defaultClient.trackRequest({
            name: context.req.method + " " + context.req.url,
            resultCode: context.res.status,
            success: true,
            url: req.url,
            duration: Date.now() - startTime,
            id: correlationContext.operation.parentId,
        });
        appInsights.defaultClient.flush();
    }, correlationContext)();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. We did tried this approach but no luck, Still we are seeing different operationId in both the functions.

Comment: Also to add on when we have Microservice-1 running locally and Microservice-2 deployed to cloud, we can see distributed tracing happening fine and operationId are same but when both Microservice 1 and Microservice 2 get deployed to Azure cloud, distributed tracing doesn't happen. Is there any configuration we need to look at while doing the deployment ?

Comment: I could not reproduce. Can you log what http headers are being passed when one microservice calls another to see if the problem lies there. I suspect correlation header is not being passed correctly due to some reason.

Comment: We are not setting the operationId anywhere explicitly in header.Is that something we need to set ?  const config={}
        // CALL TO MICROSERVICE B
        const axiosresponse= await axios["get"]("https:***.azurewebsites.net/api/logger-poc", config);
     context.res = { status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: responseMessage};

Comment: Sample code used for this is available at https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/710#issuecomment-742210871

Comment: You do not need to set it explicitly in header. What I meant is if you can log the http request header from the calle function to see what is getting passed (automatically).

Comment: Thanks for input. When I ran Microservice A locally (calling microservice B deployed in cloud) request-id and x-ms attributes are coming in request header but when Microservice A is also deployed to cloud , these headers are missing in request. These are the headers which I noticed missing   "request-id",
  "x-ms-request-id,
  "x-ms-request-root-id",   "traceparent","x-ms-coldstart" .  How to root cause why they are missing when its deployed to cloud ? is there any setting we need to look at while doing deployment which may be impacting it ?

Comment: Ahh, that's strange those headers are not being passed when deployed! So now we know that's the reason for correlation not being maintained. But I could not repro at my end yet. Do you have any middleware/api manager (e.g. APIM) in between which might be stripping those headers (I know it's a lame question)? Also, suggest you to try updating the npm packages (I see you have old versions from your question) for axios, function and app insights.

Comment: "@azure/functions": "1.2.0",
        "@azure/app-configuration": "1.1.0",
        "@azure/identity": "1.1.0",
        "@azure/keyvault-secrets": "4.0.2",
        "@azure/service-bus": "^7.0.0",
        "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.24",
        "applicationinsights": "1.8.8",
        "axios": "0.21.1",

Comment: I updated the versions as specified above but still no luck. There is no middleware also I am making direct function URL calls.

Comment: Since it's not reproducible at my end, suggest you reach Azure support to take a closer look at your specific environment/setup.

Comment: Does the plan makes any difference? we are running on consumption plan

Comment: My test was in consumption plan itself.

Comment: on further investigation noticed that when we deploy directly from visual studio code, distributed tracing is working but when deployed through azure pipeline tasks it not working. Is there any specific code we need to include to allow appinsight agent to pass required headers while using pipeline tasks?

Comment: Which task you are using in pipeline to deploy function app?

Comment: We are using - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
              displayName: "Azure Function App Deploy: ${{Parameters.servicename}}"
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: "${{Parameters.svc_conn}}"
                appType: functionApp
                appName: "$(OP_FUNCAPP_NAME)"
                #Uncomment the next lines to deploy to a deployment slot
                deployToSlotOrASE: true
                slotName: '<Slot name>'
                resourceGroupName: '$(OP_FUNCAPPRG_NAME)'
                package: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip"

Comment: Is your function app Linux or Windows?

Comment: we are using Windows

Comment: On further analysis we noticed that as we were using webpack it was getting only the dependents required to run the functions .We added a step in Azure pipeline to do npm install to include node_modules into dist folder. After this changes distributed tracing seems to be working fine.

By doing this our bundle size is getting increased , can you please suggest if this is right way to do or is there any other approach.

Comment: I am not sure if using webpack in Function is officially supported. You should [Run your Azure Functions from a package file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package). Also check the [notice](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack#note-this-repository-is-no-longer-actively-maintained) from the FuncPack author.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the code examples in the documentation worked (as the answer from @krishg illustrates), but with one difference, when setting up the `appInsights` object:

```
const appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights
    .setup('<the key>')
  .setDistributedTracingMode(appInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI_AND_W3C)
    .setAutoCollectPerformance(false);

appInsights.defaultClient.config.samplingPercentage = 100; // 100% of all telemetry will be sent to Application Insights

appInsights.start();
```